# What's the meaning of "seekable" stream?

Tags: c#, stream

I know there are *seekable streams*(like MemoryStream and FileStream) and *non-seekable streams*(like Network Stream).
**MSDN says about seek method**

> Seeking to any location beyond the length of the stream is supported.

But I didn't understand that! I tried to find an answer in the web but I failed.

Comment: It allwos you to set the position in a stream to any. For example: read first 4 bytes of file from begging. The set seek to 2. You can read last two bytes again. When seek is higher od the length of stream, it will be automatically expandend (fe. file size will become bigger).

Comment: Found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx

Comment: Note that your title does not match the final question. What are you asking about?

Comment: Warning! A `FileStream` is not necessarily seekable. [The docs read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=net-5.0): "The stream does not support seeking, such as if the ``FileStream`` is constructed from a pipe or console output."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Seekable` means you can manually set the position of the *cursor* within the stream, i.e. you can read/write a byte at any location. You're not obliged to read a byte so the cursor position is incremented.

Seeking after the current stream length will basically expand the stream length (for example your file will grow for a FileStream).